# Jackson conversion execution time/order and @JsonAnySetter

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to control a POJO with this field

```
private ObjectNode inner_data;
```

The idea here is that anything not recognised is placed into this object, and it converts to the below:

```
{
    ...
    "inner_data": {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Currently I'm using this method:

```
@JsonAnySetter
private void setUnknownProperty(String key, JsonNode value) {
    data.set(key, value);
}
```

Which is doing the job just fine. **However** the problem arises when I already have an `inner_data` field inside the JSON I'm working with - in this case Jackson may call `setUnknownProperty` for several fields, and then simply overwrite the `inner_data` object using the one in the JSON, meaning I lose fields.

Is there a way to tell Jackson to convert JSON to the `inner_data` object before it does anything else? So that `setUnknownProperty` will always write to it **after** the initial population?

**Edit**: I believe one solution is just to override `setInnerData` and tell it to only add to the existing `inner_data`... But I'd like something more elegant.

Comment: Your solution with setInnerData looks nice. In this case you won't lose the inner_data value.

Comment: afaik the properties of the bean are set in the order they're encountered in the JSON, so "buffering" all the unrecognised properties and setting them at the end would be additional work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with the solution I suggested as a workaround inside the original question:

I simply set a `setInnerData` method to only merge with the existing value for it, to avoid clobbering old values.

I'll mark this as solved, but if anyone has anything better feel free to throw it in and I'll switch the accepted answer.